# Trying to embed a platform view but the PrerollContext does not support embedding in youtube_player_flutter

Tags: flutter, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to embed youtube video in my app but video always loading. I'm using `youtube_player_flutter` 
I see in the console it throws `Trying to embed a platform view but the PrerollContext does not support embedding`

```
YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: "a5SxyQ-9YDA",
);

YoutubePlayer(
  controller: _controller,
  showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
),
```